# Why is my code skipping to the next .then before completing the prior code?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am trying to do these things in order:

1. Establish a connection to my MySQL database
2. Use cheerios and axios to return data from a website
3. Parse and "UPDATE" my database
4. Destroy the hanging connection to my MySQL database

I create the connection in the opening async function and am able to do everything I want.  The issue I am having is that, when I use a `.then` on my opening function, it doesn't wait for everything to complete before it terminates the connection.

The only workaround I have been able to use is the:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    destroy_connection();
},20000);
```

so it looks like:

```
openingFunction();
setTimeout(()=>{
    destroy_connection();
},20000);
```

What I want is to have it work like this:

```
openingFunction()
.then(() =>{
destroy_connection();
})
```

An easy way to illustrate this issue is this:

```
let nums = [1,2,3,]
function logNums(array){
    for(const elem of array){
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(elem)},3000);
    }
}
//logNums(nums);
async function run(){
     await logNums(nums)
console.log('destory connection');
}
run();
```

Results:

```
//destory connection
//1
//2
//3
```

Where as I believe it should wait for the 1,2,3 then 'destory connection'

What am I missing here?

Comment: `logNums` doesn't return a promise to be awaited.

Comment: If you're working with async/await, you generally don't want to use timeouts for demonstrator code: `async` functions are syntactic sugar for a function that returns a promise (`async () => 4` is equivalent to `() => new Promise(resolve => resolve(4))`), so if you want to use timeouts to demonstrate your problem, you'll have to write _normal_ functions that return a Promise that resolves/rejects inside your timeout.

Comment: Please post your actual code with mysql, cheerio and axios (leaving out details about what in particular is parsed etc). Otherwise we have no idea what's happening and how timing doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function  logNums returns no promise, it does not wait for completiong you can try using folowing function

```
async function logNums(array){
for(const elem of array){
    await new Promise(resolve=>{
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(elem)
            resolve()
        },3000);
    })
}
```

}

Comment: The above function will do the work in sequence. If you do not care about the order of execution, you can use Promise.all, push it in an array and await that array instead of awaiting all promises one by one